# Using MaterialFX in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder, materialfx

I've been trying to use [MaterialFX](https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX) (which is a JavaFX design library (like jFoenix)) in IntelliJ but I didn't succeed to do so. I've added the required dependency:

[image: Maven Dependency]

Also, I've added the `requires org.glavo.materialfx.adapter;` in module-info.java:

```
module org.example {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires com.jfoenix;
    requires org.glavo.materialfx.adapter;

    opens org.example to javafx.fxml;
    exports org.example;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how can I use this library because the author didn't really explain well how to do so. I would like to mention that it works perfectly in Scene Builder's latest version so I just wonder why it doesn't do so in IntelliJ.

Comment: You should provide the code which is failing as an [mcve] in the question, then it is easier for somebody to replicate your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use Maven (or Gradle) for dependency management**

You are using Maven (at least that is what the screenshot shows in Idea, though it could be Gradle making use of a Maven repository).

You should define the dependency as a maven dependency in your `pom.xml` (or `build.gradle`) then reimport the build file into Idea.

You should not manually set library dependencies in Idea.

Idea and Maven will recognize that you have a modular project and, when you have the dependency defined in Maven, they will automatically put the new dependent module on the modulepath for compilation and execution.

The maven artifact can be found by searching the maven repository:

- https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.github.palexdev/materialfx/11.13.5/jar

The dependency info is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.palexdev</groupId>
  <artifactId>materialfx</artifactId>
  <version>11.13.5</version>
</dependency>
```

The module-info for MaterialsFX requires `VirtualizedFX`.  The VirtualizedFX module also needs to be on your module path.  The pom.xml file for MaterialsFX has a includes a dependency on `io.github.palexdev:virtualizedfx:11.2.6`.  So the dependent module will be accessible for your build and runtime automatically via Mavan and Idea's inbuilt integration with the Java Platform Module System.

**Require the correct module name**

The module name for the library is not `org.glavo.materialfx.adapter`, it is [`MaterialFX`](https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX/blob/main/materialfx/src/main/java/module-info.java), so you should use:

```
requires MaterialFX;
```

NOT:

```
requires org.glavo.materialfx.adapter;
```

I recommend that you spend some time studying tutorials for your build tool and the Java Platform Module System.

**Example app**

Example was created by running the idea [new JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html), then modifying the resultant project.

*pom.xml*

In addition to having a dependency for the MaterialFX library, you also need to have dependencies for both javafx-controls and javafx-fxml.

MaterialFX requires both of these transitively at build and runtime (even if you don't use fxml in your application).

The MaterialFX pom.xml does not have an explicit dependency configuration for JavaFX, so you need to define those dependencies in your project pom.xml (which you would want to do in any case to ensure that your application is using a specific JavaFX version).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>material</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>material</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.palexdev</groupId>
            <artifactId>materialfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.13.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>18</source>
                    <target>18</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

*module-info.java*

```
module com.example.material {
    requires MaterialFX;   
    exports com.example.material;
}
```

*MaterialApplication.java*

```
package com.example.material;

import io.github.palexdev.materialfx.controls.MFXButton;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MaterialApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new MFXButton("mfx")));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well thanks a lot, it worked fine for me but without adding the "virtualizedfx" dependency which caused an error when adding. One question that I would like to ask here instead of opening a new thread. You can how can I allow JFXTextField and JFXPassword in IntelliJ latest versions? Those are jFoenix components that IntelliJ produces an error when using it even though they work regularly in Scene Builder version 15 and below.

Comment: For jfoenix bugs, [raise the bugs at the jfoenix site](https://github.com/sshahine/JFoenix/issues).  Though, I would not expect anybody to do anything about it.  There are many outstanding issues for jfoenix and only two commits to the project in the last year.  The project is not maintained.  So expect functionality that does not work to continue not to work unless you fix it.

Comment: "it worked fine for me but without adding the "virtualizedfx" dependency" -> Yes, I double-checked, the MaterialFX `pom.xml` has a dependency on `virtualizedfx` and references it in its `module-info.java`.  So the correct version of the dependent library will automatically due to your toolsets integration with the java module system.  You don't need to manually add the virtualizedfx library to the project dependencies in order for it to be available for use.  I updated the answer to clarify this.