# Error with JFXTextField from JFoenix: module java.base does not "opens java.lang.reflect" to module com.jfoenix

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, jfoenix

I'm using IntelliJ and Gradle with JavaFX and wanted to test the JFoenix package (https://github.com/sshahine/JFoenix).

If I drag and drop a JFXTextField with the SceneBuilder in my scene, the application doesn't start anymore. This problem occurs for example not for a JFXButton.

Tested Java 17 and 11, SceneBuilder 17 and 15 but the problem still occurs.
Adding JVM Options like described here (https://github.com/bisq-network/bisq/pull/5835) doesn't help aswell.

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

module-info.java:

```
module test {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.core;
    requires com.jfoenix;

    opens ...
    exports...
}
```

Thanks for any idea.

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make boolean java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible0(boolean) accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang.reflect" to module com.jfoenix
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:280)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:192)
    at com.jfoenix/com.jfoenix.adapters.ReflectionHelper.<clinit>(ReflectionHelper.java:48)
    at com.jfoenix/com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTextFieldSkin.<init>(JFXTextFieldSkin.java:59)
    at com.jfoenix/com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField.createDefaultSkin(JFXTextField.java:69)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:897)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.access$000(Control.java:83)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:1397)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.access$400(Parent.java:79)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$1.doProcessCSS(Parent.java:125)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.ParentHelper.processCSSImpl(ParentHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9529)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doCSSPass(Scene.java:569)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1745)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$2.preferredSize(Scene.java:393)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.preferredSize(SceneHelper.java:66)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1086)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1174)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1189)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:273)
    at com.github.devenrico.hospitalmanagement@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.github.devenrico.hospitalmanagement.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:17)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jfoenix/com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTextFieldSkin.updateTextPos(JFXTextFieldSkin.java:109)
    at com.jfoenix/com.jfoenix.skins.JFXTextFieldSkin.layoutChildren(JFXTextFieldSkin.java:93)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.layoutChildren(Control.java:601)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1204)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1211)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:576)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1748)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$2.preferredSize(Scene.java:393)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.preferredSize(SceneHelper.java:66)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1086)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1174)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1189)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:273)
    at com.github.devenrico.hospitalmanagement@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.github.devenrico.hospitalmanagement.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:17)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.github.devenrico.hospitalmanagement.HelloApplication

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.13\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
15:27:09: Execution finished 'run --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=com.jfoenix'.
```

Comment: I advise using [MaterialFX](https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX) instead, it seems less buggy than jfoenix, given the current question profile on StackOverflow.  Sample [usage via Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71931192/using-materialfx-in-intellij/71931282#71931282), but Gradle will be similar.

Comment: Your [linked project](https://github.com/sshahine/JFoenix/blob/master/jfoenix/build.gradle) uses something called ["retrolambda](https://github.com/luontola/retrolambda), which " lets you run Java 8 code with lambda expressions, method references and try-with-resources statements on Java 7, 6 or 5. It does this by transforming your Java 8 compiled bytecode so that it can run on an older Java runtime.".  I doubt you would want to do such a thing with a modern JavaFX distribution app.  Maybe investigate [gluon mobile instead](https://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/).

Answer (score 0):

You should put this arguments to jvm:

`--add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=com.jfoenix  --add-exports javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior=com.jfoenix`