# Using Java FX 19, add jfoenix date picker I gor error with Maven

Tags: maven, javafx

Using Java FX 19, add jfoenix date picker I gor error with Maven

Error Message :

```
 superclass access check failed: class com.jfoenix.controls.behavior.JFXGenericPickerBehavior (in unnamed module @0x3bc0c794) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ComboBoxBaseBehavior (in module javafx.controls) because module javafx.controls does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior to unnamed module @0x3bc0c794
```

What is the solution for this?

Comment: It looks as though `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior` is not exported by Java FX19 which possibly is a change between JavaFX releases? Try an earlier version of JavaFX. I wonder if that was intended to be a package not for public consumption and has only been made private in JavaFX 19. Never good for a library to rely on internal packages.

Comment: JFoenix relied on accessing non-public API in JavaFX 8, which is why (imo) it was destined to failure. My recommendation would simply be not to use it, though you may be able to get it to work if you make sure you are using a version and configuration compatible with a modern version of JavaFX and the JDK. Some people find MaterialFX a suitable alternative, or, of course, just use the standard JavaFX controls.

Comment: Short tutorial on [using MaterialFX via Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71931192/using-materialfx-in-intellij/71931282#71931282) if you need it.

Comment: @D-Dᴙum "*I wonder if that was intended to be a package not for public consumption*" -> your supposition is correct.  None of the `com.sun.javafx` API was intended for public consumption.  Prior to JavaFX modularization in JavaFX 11, there was no way to enforce hiding of `com.sun.javafx` APIs from code that was not part of the framework.  With modularization of JavaFX 11+, by default, none of the `com.sun.javafx` code is accessible outside of the JavaFX modules anymore.